# Search bar content is not getting fixed in center even after both "align-items:center; justify-content:center"

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a search bar inside a navigation bar. Here the problem I am facing is that **search bar** content is not getting align in the center even after both the properties are present `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center`. Help me justifying the content of the search bar in the center.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-shadow: 7px 2px 10px red;
  margin: 0px;
}


/*--------------------------------------Search Box-------------------------------------- */

.search-box {
  position: absolute;
  /* top: 50%; */
  right: 0;
  /* transform: translate(-50%); */
  background: #2f3640;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* .search-box:hover>.search-text {
            width: 240px;
            padding: 0 6px;

        } */

.search-btn {
  color: #e84118;
  float: right;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.search-text {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 240px
}


/*--------------------------------------Search Box-------------------------------------- */

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  background-color: black;
  /* position: sticky; */
  /* top: 0; */
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  /* border-radius: 15px; */
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.dropbutton {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 80px;
  /* font-weight: bold; */
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 14.5px;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  max-width: 95px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: white;
}


/* .row {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        } */

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  /* flex: 30%; */
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  ;
}

.fakeimg {
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.row::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  /* position: relative; */
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-vSIIfh2YWi9wW0r9iZe7RJPrKwp6bG+s9QZMoITbCckVJqGCCRhc+ccxNcdpHuYu" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>layout-practice</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Header element -->
  <div class="header">
    <h1>!!!Hello World!!!</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- Navigation Bar -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Home">Blogs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Home">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Switch">Switch</a>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropbutton" href="#Home">Settings</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#Account">Account</a>
          <a href="#Notification">Notification</a>
          <a href="#Password">Password</a>
          <a href="#Lougout">Logout</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- --------------------------------------Search Box--------------------------------------  -->
      <div class="search-box">
        <input class="search-text" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Type to search">
        <a class="search-btn" href="#search">
          <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- --------------------------------------Search Box--------------------------------------  -->
  </ul>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      <h1>My profile</h1>
      <h5>Photo of me</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height: 200px;">Image</div>
      <P>This is my profile and i am the creater of this page. This is my profile and i am the creater of this page.
      </P>
      <h3>More Info.</h3>
      <p>Here are some of my work portfolio:</p>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height: 100px;">Image</div><br>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height: 100px;">Image</div><br>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height: 100px;">Image</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h1>Title Heading</h1>
      <h5> Title description Tue, Mar 9, 2021</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height: 200px;">Image</div>
      <p>Related Information</p>
      <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.
      </p>
      <br>
      <h1>Title Heading</h1>
      <h5> Title description Tue, Mar 9, 2021</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height: 200px;">Image</div>
      <h3>Related Information</h3>
      <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <h1>Fotter</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `padding` from the search box and add `text-align: center` to `.search-text`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-shadow: 7px 2px 10px red;
  margin: 0px;
}


/*--------------------------------------Search Box-------------------------------------- */

.search-box {
  position: absolute;
  /* top: 50%; */
  right: 0;
  /* transform: translate(-50%); */
  background: #2f3640;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
}


/* .search-box:hover>.search-text {
                width: 240px;
                padding: 0 6px;
    
            } */

.search-btn {
  color: #e84118;
  float: right;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.search-text {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 240px;
  text-align: center;
}


/*--------------------------------------Search Box-------------------------------------- */

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  background-color: black;
  /* position: sticky; */
  /* top: 0; */
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  /* border-radius: 15px; */
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.dropbutton {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 80px;
  /* font-weight: bold; */
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 14.5px;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  max-width: 95px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: white;
}


/* .row {
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
            } */

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  /* flex: 30%; */
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  ;
}

.fakeimg {
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.row::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  /* position: relative; */
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-vSIIfh2YWi9wW0r9iZe7RJPrKwp6bG+s9QZMoITbCckVJqGCCRhc+ccxNcdpHuYu" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>layout-practice</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Header element -->
  <div class="header">
    <h1>!!!Hello World!!!</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- Navigation Bar -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Home">Blogs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Home">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Switch">Switch</a>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropbutton" href="#Home">Settings</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#Account">Account</a>
          <a href="#Notification">Notification</a>
          <a href="#Password">Password</a>
          <a href="#Lougout">Logout</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- --------------------------------------Search Box--------------------------------------  -->
      <div class="search-box">
        <input class="search-text" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Type to search">
        <a class="search-btn" href="#search">
          <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- --------------------------------------Search Box--------------------------------------  -->

  </ul>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      <h1>My profile</h1>
      <h5>Photo of me</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height: 200px;">Image</div>
      <P>This is my profile and i am the creater of this page. This is my profile and i am the creater of this page.
      </P>
      <h3>More Info.</h3>
      <p>Here are some of my work portfolio:</p>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height: 100px;">Image</div><br>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height: 100px;">Image</div><br>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height: 100px;">Image</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <h1>Title Heading</h1>
      <h5> Title description Tue, Mar 9, 2021</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height: 200px;">Image</div>
      <p>Related Information</p>
      <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.
      </p>
      <br>
      <h1>Title Heading</h1>
      <h5> Title description Tue, Mar 9, 2021</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height: 200px;">Image</div>
      <h3>Related Information</h3>
      <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <h1>Fotter</h1>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The padding of your `search-box` is pushing its content down, as you have the same fixed height for the `search-box`, including the padding, a total of `40px`, and the input line height, which is also `40px`.

Answer (score 1):

Add into .search-text class height: 25px; and into .search-btn class height: 25px;